# Linear Regression not Defined

Tags: python, linear-regression, knn

Previously had code and did not have any issues not it is giving an error of not having "Linear Regression" defined. Code below, not sure what I am missing.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

model2 = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
x_poly = model2.fit_transform(X_train)
model2.fit(x_poly, y_train)
poly_reg = LinearRegression()
poly_reg.fit(x_poly, y_train)
m2_pred = poly_reg.predict(model2.fit_transform(X_test))
```

I have tried google and other sources and not finding resolution, previously code worked.

Comment: You're not defining `LinearRegression()` or importing it from anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You need to import [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) at the top of your code.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```